# What is the best way to draw simple line on image in django app

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am still new in django and I want to ask if I have a form to upload image what is the best way to edit it by drawing simple line upon the image in web based simple photo editor

Comment: This is more of a Python question than Django. You should have a look at PIL/Pillow for general image manipulation.

Comment: May app is web based using django

Comment: I can see that, but Django has no built-in functionality to manipulate images. It is either a Javascript (client side) or a Python (server side) question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow this tutorial [About Canvas](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/), So you can build your custom drawing app.
For example this little code that draws a line over an Image. [code](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/5a2LR/)

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="demo" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('demo'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    line = new Line(ctx),
    img = new Image;


function Line(ctx) {

    var me = this;

    this.x1 = 0;
    this.x2 = 0;
    this.y1 = 0;
    this.y2 = 0;

    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(me.x1, me.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(me.x2, me.y2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

img.onload = start;
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/O712qpO.jpg';

function start() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);
    canvas.onmousemove = updateLine;
}

function updateLine(e) {
    var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = e.clientX - r.left,
        y = e.clientY - r.top;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    line.x1 = x;
    line.y1 = 0;
    line.x2 = x;
    line.y2 = canvas.height;
    line.draw();
}
```